# Alternative to jQuery Mobile changePage functionality

Tags: jquery

I've been working on a desktop version of a jQuery mobile application I developed. To re-use some of the code base, I thought i would use JQM for the desktop version of the application as well.

Turns out that it causes all kinds of problems with the design whenever I load up JQM (mainly because I do all kinds of stuff with native UI elements). Now, I'm actually only interested in the `$.mobile.changePage` functionality, so it's overkill to actually use this framework just for that.

My question is, does anybody know of some jQuery plugin that holds the same functionality as the `changePage` function in JQM? (including checking for back buttons, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this plugin exists, especially when you say 'including checking for back buttons, etc' that mean that you almost want the whole 'navigation model' of JQM.

Basically $.mobile.changePage calls loadPage which loads the html (page object or from url) via ajax into the dom (and enhance the markup) and after that shows this in the $.mobile.pageContainer with or without a transition.

I think it is possible to do this yourself, but it depends on how your code is structured, you can define html blocks (in hidden divs or in local html files) and load this into a 'container' by using $.ajax

Comment: Yeah, i ended up writing the whole thing myself. It was quite the learning experience but ultimately possible because of the hashchange plugin. It works wonders!